# Webpack: Copy javascript files to output directory without processing them

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have a typescript project setup with webpack. This project also contains some javascript files that should be copied to the output directory *without* processing them in any way.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any chance you could check the [`configuration`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html). I guess `entry` or `externals` might be a way to go, or you could go for the `noParse` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can identify those file. May with some glob patter or by direct file name. Then use

[copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin)

Comment: Great, that's what I am using now: `new CopyWebpackPlugin([{from: "src/integration/integration.loader.*.js", flatten: true}])`

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't try to do that with WebPack... 
Just copy the files with an npm script.
lets say somenthing like this in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "deldist": "rimraf ./assets/dist",
   "copy": "copy command here",
   "prod": "npm run deldist && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules --display-error-details && npm run copy"
 },
```

...
then you could run

```
npm run prod
```

Comment: Why would I? Webpack is performing all my bundling tasks and copying other static files like images already. JS files is just a bit more tricky because they would be processed. Still, its webpacks job to do copy them

Comment: thats the easy way... you can , if you want, look for a loader or make your own loader